# SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH equivalent in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I need to convert my Oracle query into SQL Server.

The query generates a "management hierarchy" based on usernames. The output will have a management chain with the last element being the current manager.

Table:

```
EE_USERNAME     MGR_USERNAME  
user1       ceo
user2       user1
user3       user2
user4       user1
user5       user2
user6       user3
```

Sample Output:

```
user1: ceo
user2: ceo,user1
user3: ceo,user1,user2
user4: ceo,user1
user5: ceo,user1,user2
user6: ceo,user1,user2,user3
```

My Oracle query for this:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_DATA.* ,  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(MGR_USERNAME, ',') "Path"
FROM EMPLOYEE_DATA
START WITH MGR_USERNAME = 'ceo'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE  prior  EE_USERNAME = MGR_USERNAME
```

What would be the SQL Server equivalent of this query?

Comment: You probably want to investigate a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.*, mgr.EE_USERNAME AS Path
        FROM EMPLOYEE_DATA AS mgr
        JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA AS e ON mgr.EE_USERNAME = e.MGR_USERNAME
        WHERE mgr.EE_USERNAME = 'ceo'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.*, mgr.Path + ',' + mgr.EE_USERNAME AS Path
        FROM cte AS mgr
        JOIN EMPLOYEE_DATA e ON mgr.EE_USERNAME = e.MGR_USERNAME
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
-- OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200)  -- if you need a different value
;
```

If you are doing a lot of recursion, you should take a look at `MAXRECURSION` which has a default of 100.

Comment: Thank you, this works!  Is it expected that the query processing time will be much slower than Oracle?

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow. I cannot find an option to Accept Answer and close thread, could you guide me? Thank you!

Comment: The check mark on the left side. Probably the same perf, ie good but not great and should be avoided except for these types of queries. It uses a very fast temp table under the hood, but with large amounts of data or a lot of recursion it can be slow. Don't forget to look up `OPTION (MAXRECURSION...`

Answer (score 0):

Charlieface's query omits the functionality provided by Oracle's NOCYCLE directive which says to cease recursion if the same record comes back a second time.

If you want this protection, you can add a Where clause to the recursive section of the CTE query:

```
Where Instr(mgr.EE_Username,mgr.Path)=0
```